# Задача на пересечение двух множеств. C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=82):

> Даны два неупорядоченных набора целых чисел (может быть, с
> повторениями). Выдать без повторений в порядке возрастания все те
> числа, которые встречаются в обоих наборах.
>
> **Входные данные** В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано через
> пробел два целых числа N и М (1 ≤ N, М ≤ 300 000) — количество
> элементов первого и второго наборов, соответственно. В следующих
> строках записано сначала N чисел первого набора, а затем M чисел
> второго набора. Числа разделены пробелами или символами конца строки.
> Каждое из этих чисел попадает в промежуток от 0 до 10^5.
>
> **Выходные данные** В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно записать в
> возрастающем порядке без повторений все числа, которые входят как в
> первый, так и во второй набор. Числа разделять одним пробелом. Если
> таких чисел нет, то выходной файл должен оставаться пустым.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool dp[100001];

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        dp[x] = true;
    }
    vector<int> ans;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (dp[x])
            ans.push_back(x);
    }
    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    for (auto& b : ans)
        cout << b << " ";
}
```

Решил сделать все с помощью запоминания чисел. Однако данное решение засчитывается как неверное. А контр-пример найти мне не удалось. В чем может быть проблема?

И параллельный вопрос: я объявляю массив dp однако он автоматически инициализируется нулями. А почему? По идее не должен же?...

Comment: Вы объявили массив как глобальную переменную - значит, должен обнуляться.

Comment: Контрпример `1 2 \n 1 1 1`. Результат должен быть `1` а не `1 1`

Comment: @extrn точно! вы правы, сейчас подправлю свою программу...

Comment: также желательно резервировать память для вектора, чтобы избежать перераспределений памяти и много копирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool dp[100001];

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        dp[x] = true;
    }
    vector<int> ans;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (dp[x])
        {
            ans.push_back(x);
            dp[x] = false; //<--- решение
        }

    }
    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    for (auto& b : ans)
        cout << b << " ";
}
```

спасибо [@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn)